# Moving pair content from one pair to another in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I just started learning STL and looking for an example for the below items:

```
pair<T1,T2> p(rv1,rv2) // moving items individually
pair<T1,T2> p(rv) // moving complete pair
```

Here "RV" denotes creating an pair p with moving elements instead of copying. I am looking for an example which shows me how to move pair values.

Comment: Do what? What are `rv1`, `rv2`, and `rv`? Why do you want to move them? It is completely unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, maybe you are looking for this (?):

```
pair<T1,T2> p(std::move(rv1),std::move(rv2)); // moving items individually
pair<T1,T2> p(std::move(rv));  // move pair
```

Comment: Thanks jarek. This is what i was looking.